# Migrating from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.1 64 bit

Tags: server, rdp, teamviewer

Couple of questions before we as a company migrate:

Our server is Windows 2008 std. Will it support Ubuntu clients?
Data backed-up from Windows client can it be restored on Ubuntu
We connect to remote Servers thru Remote Desktop.. will Remmina work?
Normal usage software like Adobe/VLC/Teamviewer work on Ubuntu?

Thanks & Regards
Sanjiv

Comment: Buy or designate a sacrificial computer. Install Ubuntu. Try it. Anything anyone tells you is insignificant compared to actual experience.

Comment: Makes Sense Walti

Answer (score 0):

Some advice for doing windows stuff on ubuntu: try installing wine, it does the job. download [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) or you can search for it on the ubuntu software center.